# JQuery Onchange when not changed

Tags: jquery

I am using:

```
 $('#input1').change(function() { 

          $('#input2').val($(this).val());

 });
```

The above works fine when you add or change something.

My question is, what do I use when I want to get the value of input1 and assign it to input2 eventhough input1 has not been changed?

Comment: the line `$('#input2').val($(this).val());` will do, just call it whenever you need

Comment: @Banana what about $(this)?

Comment: Do you want this on page load

Comment: Replace it with `$("#input1")` of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger it somehow.

For example with a button.

```
$("myButtonSelector").click(function(){
   $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
});
```

or on focus

```
$("#input1").focus(function(){
   $("#input2").val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Or on any other event you would need.

Answer (score 1):

use trigger to change

```
$('#input1').change(function() { 

          $('#input2').val($(this).val());

 }).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below script to add value on page load :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
});
```